# what web service to use to find the street and the intersection from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, javascript, maps

I am developing an APP in Ionic 4 and I need to call a service where I send the latitude and longitude to indicate the streets
The web service would like it to be free to use and try
I've already tried with nominatim it's very good, it just does not give me back the closest intersection of the street, it just returns the main street
Sorry for my English
Thank you